Razer Viper V3 Pro Double-Clicks on Single Click
I recently bought a Razer Viper V3 Pro for hardcore gaming, and I'm facing a frustrating issue. The mouse often double-clicks when I only intend to single-click. This problem is especially annoying during gaming sessions.
I've tried the following troubleshooting steps so far:

Adjusted the double-click speed in the mouse settings.
Checked for any firmware updates and installed the latest version.
Tried using the mouse on different surfaces and USB ports.
Cleaned the mouse buttons to ensure there's no debris causing the issue.

Despite these efforts, the problem persists. Has anyone else experienced this with the Razer Viper V3 Pro, or does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix it? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

More often than not this is a defective switch. If you have only recently bought it then take it back and get it replaced.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
